# inline editing in row append to other table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending row from one html table to other. I want to do inline editing in append row to other table. Below is my jquery code which append row to other html table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {        
      if (index == 1) {
        $('#tblPurchaseOrders').find('tr:has(td)').each(function() {
          if (parseInt(($(this).find('#Quantity')).val()) > 0)
            $(this).appendTo('#tbOrderDetail');
        });        
      }    
    }
  });
});
```

A complete working example can be found on below link. Pardon for any mistake.

http://jsfiddle.net/azeemhafeez75/x4k7yhye/85/

Comment: You forget to ask a question.

Comment: I mentioned above how to do inline editing in append row to other html table.

Comment: Ok so it's just for knowledge purpose?

Comment: No. I am implementing wizard form in which first tab is entry form and second tab is confirmation tab where he can delete the row or he can edit the row.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explain what you are trying and how to reproduce the issue you are facing?

Comment: Dear its very simple. I want to do inline editing in row which i am appending to other table. If you follow the above link it will clear all your question.